# scrollIntoView - behavior is not working(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, smooth-scrolling, js-scrollintoview

I know there are other questions on stackOverflow with the same question(2016 and older), but I went through them all and they do not solve my problem.

scroll into view works, when I click the button then the page goes to the specfic section it is suppose to go to but the behavior propery does not function.

```
const alllinks = document.querySelectorAll("scroll:link");

alllinks.forEach(function (link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = link.getAttribute("href");
    // Scroll to top
    if (href === "#") {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    }
    //Scroll to other links
    else if (href !== "#" && href.startsWith("#")) {
      document.getElementById(href).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: `smooth`,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Here's how the html looks at all the sections. (This is only one section as a example)

```html
<a class="scroll nav-list--item btn" href="#how">How it works</a>
<section class="section-more container" id='how'>...</section>
```

This is all the code needed.

[CODE PEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/rabierabit/pen/bGRByKJ)

Comment: `it is suppose to go to but`? Hmmm? Please describe the problem properly. Also, seeing the corresponding HTML would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**getElementById**'s argument must be the element id value and do not contain "#".

```
 document.getElementById(href).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: `smooth`,
  });
```

This block of code throws TypeError because document.getElementById(href) with href = "#how" will return undefined, so when you was clicked in the link, the scroll behavior is just default behavior of the **a** link.
May be you can want to correct it like:

```
document.getElementById(href.slice(1)).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: `smooth`,
  });
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but this makes no difference at all

Comment: I've edited your pen and it's worked. Please take a look
https://codepen.io/vdloc/pen/xxrRorz

Comment: and your anchor tag selector syntax (document.querySelectorAll("scroll:link")) is new to me and when I inspected it, it doesn't return any link element so I've change the selector to "a[class^=scroll]" or a[href^='#'].

Comment: I dont understand a[href^='#'] and the reason I put it as 'scroll:link' is because I have different buttons that lead to different pages, so the buttons that had to have the smooth scrolling I gave a scroll class so that all the buttons dont get a smooth scroll

and also even tho I dont know what that means Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Add these additional properties too to make it work

```
element.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'start',
  inline: 'nearest'
});
```

EDIT: in you case, you just need to put the below css in your main style file, because the scrolling is not happening by the javascript code you wrote, it is happening because of the href of  tag. you can even remove the javascript code

```
* {
    scroll-behavior: smooth
 }
```

Comment: This does not work, I have tried it previosly, tried it again now and still doenst work

Comment: can you please share https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to reproduce the issue

Comment: Everything needeed is there

Comment: Updated the answer according to your case, hopefully this will help you understand the situation you are facing.